# Does a silvered weapon overcome resistance to non-magical attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, damage-resistance

My friends and I had a question about [silvered weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#SilveredWeapons). Will it overcome the resistance to non-magical weapons?

For example, [Rakshasa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16990-rakshasa) is resistant to non-magical attacks. Will an attack with a silvered weapon deal him full damage or will it have no effect at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Applying silver does not make a weapon magical.

The rules for silvering weapons read:

> Some monsters that have immunity or resistance to nonmagical weapons are susceptible to silver weapons, so cautious adventurers invest extra coin to plate their weapons with silver. You can silver a single weapon or ten pieces of ammunition for 100 gp. This cost represents not only the price of the silver, but the time and expertise needed to add silver to the weapon without making it less effective.

Nothing here says the weapon becomes magical, so a nonmagical weapon does not become magical. Monsters that are susceptible to silvered weapons will have that annotated in their stat blocks. For example, the Bone Devil:

> **Damage Resistances** Cold; Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks that aren't Silvered

A silvered weapon overcomes the Bone Devil's resistance to nonmagical weapons *because the resistance text explicitly states that it is only resistant to attacks from weapons that are not silvered.*

In contrast, the Rakshasa's immunity reads:

> **Damage Immunities** Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks

Since a silvered weapon delivers a nonmagical attack, and no exception is made for silvered weapons in the immunity text, the Rakshasa is totally immune to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage from silvered weapons, unless the weapon just happens to also be a magical weapon. Applying silver to a weapon does not make it magical, but silver can be applied to a magical weapon, yielding a magical silver weapon.

Answer (score -3):

By RAW(Rules as Written), no. A typical house rule is to have silvered weapons become +0 magical ones for this purpose, but they are not considered magical in the default rules.

Comment: Do you have any documents you can cite about this "typical house rule"? As I've been playing since 1st ed and have never encountered it.

Comment: @MivaScott Indeed, I've also never used, or even heard, of such a house rule.